# C# String Sort with Leading Decimal Numbers?

Tags: c#, sorting, lambda

```
    2.1-hello
    2.2-world
    2.3-people
    2.10-everywhere
```

results in this when items are added to a `SortedDictionary<String,String>`

```
    2.1-hello
    2.10-everywhere
    2.2-world
    2.3-people
```

What is the best way to get the sort with the behavior decimal/numeric order before the "-" character, with conventional ASCII order/collation after that? Original code was splitting on the "-" and converting the initial parts, which is really not efficient. All ideas appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `SortedDictionary<String>` does not compile. Please add more detail to you specific requirements and provide code you have already tried.

Comment: @Barns SortedDictionary<String,String> is what I meant. Thanks for identifying that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [Natural Sort Order in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp)

But if you want a simple solution that works with your specific use-case you could have a look at the following. I don't split on the delimiter `-` but use `IndexOf` + `Remove` which is more efficient. For the natural sorting i'm using the `Version` class:

```
var list = new List<string>{"2.1-hello","2.2-world","2.3-people","2.10-everywhere", "foo"};
list = list
    .Select(s => (String:s,Version:GetVersion(s), LastPart:GetLastPart(s)))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Version)
    .ThenBy(x => x.LastPart)
    .Select(x => x.String)
    .ToList();
```

---

```
private static Version GetVersion(string s, string delimiter = "-")
{
    int index = s.IndexOf(delimiter);
    if(index == -1) return null;
    return Version.TryParse(s.Remove(index), out Version v) ? v : null;
}

private static string GetLastPart(string s, string delimiter = "-")
{
    int index = s.IndexOf(delimiter);
    if (index == -1) return s;
    return s.Substring(index + delimiter.Length);
}
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rF1YNy)